Chrome Driver not closing properly and using a lot of CPU
I am currently using Chrome Driver with Serenity BDD and when the tests are done running, it is not closing properly, and it is consuming a lot of CPU. I am unable to run a full regression before my entire PC crashes since already visibly closed chrome instances are still in the task manager consuming my CPU.
I have tried to play around with the chrome switches like turning off --no-sandbox and --disable-gpu, but those dont seem to work and I am at a bit of a loss.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Before I also had the above error when using serenity 3.1.0.
This version has a very long rendering report error, you should update to 3.2.4.
Next, the chromedriver error does not close but still runs, you can see it in Taskmanger, in this part you just need to remove

--no-sandbox

from the chrome.switches config section and it will work well.
